# kibana timelion time zone issue

Tags: kibana, timelion

sorry if this is a newbie question but i have been having a very weird issue with my installation of kibana:

setting **dateFormat:tz** is set to **UTC**.
searches are working great and data is shown exactly as expected when the last minute in the graph is 3 hours before my local time (i'm at GMT+3 so it's accurate)

in time lion on the other hand I've been having an issue where i run a very basic time series like **.es(*)** and what i get is a graph where the last 3 hours is showing 0 entries. it seems that the timelion is not using the configured time zone for the graph limits but it is using the tz on the data.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your data time field

```
.es(timefield=YOURFIELDNAME)
```

Comment: the field to get the time from is set correctly to a 'timefield' containing epoch time in millis and is indexed as a date field, i tried adding this and it did not change anything ;-(